# SQL specify the date in Select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, format

I have to display hire date of all employees hired in May or November of any year, with the most recently hired employees displayed first. Also, exclude people hired in 1994 and 1995. Hire date should point to the last day in May or November of that year (NOT to the exact day), and should be in format: 
[May 31st of 1996]

here is what I got so far:

column: hire_date
table: employees

```
SELECT "[" || DATE_FORMAT(hire_date, %M %D %Y) || "]" 
FROM employees 
WHERE hire_date NOT IN ('%-%-94', '%-%-95') 
    AND hire_date in ('%-MAY-%', '%-NOV-%');
```

But it doesn`t work
Please help find correct solution.

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS you're using, e.g. Oracle, SQL-Server.

Comment: The format of the hire_date column is DD-MON-YY

Comment: Why isn't it a `DATE` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very bad idea to store dates not as `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type.
Even worse when year is build by 2 digits only.

Here a solution if HIRE_DATE is the "proper" data type:

```
SELECT FIRST, LAST, HIRE_DATE, 
  TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(HIRE_DATE),'"["Month ddTH" of "YYYY"]"') as D
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIRE_DATE) IN (5,11)
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIRE_DATE) NOT IN (1994, 1995)
ORDER BY HIRE_DATE DESC
```

In case HIRE_DATE is data type `VARCHAR2` use `TO_DATE(HIRE_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY')` instead of `HIRE_DATE`

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d93ca/12

Comment: I was about posting almost the same solution. I've edited your answer to add a link to the corresponding SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

The following works fine for Oracle:

```
SELECT '[' || TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'MM DD YYYY') || ']' AS HIRE_DATE
      FROM EMPLOYEES
      WHERE TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'YYYY') NOT IN ('1994', '1995') AND
            TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'MON') IN ('MAY', 'NOV')
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d93ca/1)

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the hire date to be displayed as the last day of the month. Then use the following in select

```
TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(HIRE_DATE), 'MM DD YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `hire_date` was stored as a char, so you could use `regexp_like`

```
NOT regexp_like (HIRE_DATE,'\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-(95|94)')
AND regexp_like (HIRE_DATE,'\d{2}-(MAY|NOV)-\d{2}')
```